Bound the size of a family of sets such that the intersection of any four sets has the size at least two
this is a question that has appeared in a undergraduate math Olympiad (CIIM 2014) and I would like some help on it.

Given $n\geq2$, let $\mathcal{A}$ be a family of subsets of the set
$\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that, for any $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4 \in \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| \leq n -2$
. Prove that $|\mathcal{A}| \leq 2^{n-2}.$

Progress so far: take the complement of each set, the condition then translates to $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| \ge 2$, this could be also understood in terms of linear algebra with vector space being $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$ in terms of vectors product.
The following line of though might not apply anymore, after I was notified that the $\ge 2$ was correct:

I'm having a lot of trouble on how to proceed on this problem because
it is just very hard to deal with four intersections at the same time,
say that the problem condition was instead $|A \cap B| \le 2$, then I
would be done because this is well known as it can be seen here
so, it might be an idea that to simultaneously apply this twice, and
maybe count the number of times that  $|A \cap B| = c$, where $c$ is a
fixed number, occurs but it seems necessary to have some knowledge on
the equality cases for this approach to be effective.

Update:
Straight induction won't work for some reasons, one of them is that the condition might be still be true (some sets even after an element deleted could still union with size $n-2$), so this might not work. Another thing that is possible is noticing that one can WLOG assume that all the subsets of some set should be in $\mathcal{A}$, so one might ignore all the other conditions and just focus on a Sperner family satisfying the problem's statement. Besides that, I'm not sure if there's any double counting lurking, I think it would be necessary some extra conditions for this to be possible.
Something else that I observed to be possible, you are able to swap to two numbers (or almost this), say that you want to $2$ in every instance of a $1$, in $\mathcal{A}$, then if a set has $1$, but not two $2$ and this doesn't create a set that is already in $\mathcal{A}$, then do this swap, otherwise, don't. Now, notice that this will preserve the problem condition and will keep the size of the set the same. So we can pick by contradiction the largest family that does not satisfy the problem with a minimized order (with as much $1$s as possible, as much $2$s as possible etc by doing as much swaps necessaries). If all the sets of the family share some element, then we can erase it. So we can also say that the intersection is null.

You should have $\geq 2$ for the intersection, right?

oh... this is quite embarrassing for me, yes it should be $\ge 2$

@lulu I have seen that mathcal problem. Take a look at the accepted answer here. I only had to do it once to fix the problem. Basically, right click on the rendered text and select "Math Settings > Math Renderer > Common HTML (instead of HTML-CSS)".

The question is correct, and works of Peter Frankl etc. have shown your answer to be right and found the answer in many situations where $4,2$ are replaced by other numbers, the keyword being $r$-wise $t$-intersecting families. The problem is that you're talking about an undergraduate olympiad, so I'm not expecting students to reproduce research work in there. Something simpler is at play, which we should try to find.

This goes back to a very old Iran olympiad. See page 90 here for the solution https://pdfcoffee.com/titu-andreescu-contests-around-the-world-1999-2000-pdf-free.html

Thanks, for the reference! Apparently this was also a P1, so I'm not sure on how to feel after failing this problem. Haha

This is a replication of the solution given in the book "Contests Around the World: 1999 - 2000" informed to us by Vlad Matei.
Notice that the union any two sets in $\mathcal{A}$ can't be equal to $\{1, \dots, n\}$, so there exists sets in $\{1, \dots, n\}$ which are not inside any union of two elements of $\mathcal{A}$, pick the smallest one in terms of size, call it $A$. Now we will use the following idea, if we fix a set $X$, then a set $Y$ is determined by its intersection with $X$ and $\overline{X}$. Here we can do the same with $A$, say that $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, \dots, A_l\}$, then let $\mathcal{A'} = \{A \cap A_1, \dots, A \cap A_l\}$, notice that if there's a set $S \in \mathcal{A'}$, then $A - S \notin \mathcal{A'}$, so at most half of the subsets of $A$ are in $\mathcal{A'}$. Now repeating the same argument with $\mathcal{A''} = \{\overline{A} \cap A_1, \dots, \overline{A} \cap A_l\}$ will solve the problem, to check that the property is indeed true in this case, assume that both $S$, and $A-S$ are in $\mathcal{A''}$, then we can find two subsets in $\mathcal{A}$ that will cover $\overline{A}$ and due to minimality of $A$, we can find other two sets $A$, and $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $A \cup B = A-{a}$ for some element $a$. This gives us a contradiction.
